# How to run USSD command like a sequence?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to run USSD code like a sequence, for example, if I dial *123# to check my credit balance, and then I have to type 2, and then 1, is there a way to call that all at once, to go directly to that menu?

Comment: If you found my answer correct, would you mind marking it as correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can dial *123*2*1#

It means you opened 123 command menu and selected 2 then selected 1, so you get the last response and call them at once.