# How to run phone's USSD in codenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to run USSD-codes via my codenameOne application. However I cannot find any documentation on how to access the phone utilities. Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

USSD codes aren't accessible from mobile applications due to security restrictions on the devices.

Comment: I have found two threads on stack overflow talking about that - and I do believe it might be managed. The first one : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025339/how-to-run-ussd-command-like-a-sequence] - proposes a dialing action. The second one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225100/how-to-run-ussd-commands-on-android] - proposes using an Android.Intent based approach. @ShaiAlmog Do you think that one of these approaches could work with CodenameOne API?

Comment: You can use a native interface to do that or use Display.dial but I never tried that.